# Opacity mask disregards ClipToBounds is True

Tags: c#, wpf, image, graphics, wpf-controls

I have a "mask canvas" that I am paining on to use as the source of the OpacityMask of my main painting canvas.

Both of my canvases are the same size, but I am getting some unexpected results when I start painting near the border of the canvas.

Ive created a gif to illustrate my problem:
[image]

In the gif, I first painted the mask (in black). Then on another canvas with its OpacityMask binded to the mask canvas, I began painting with a grass texture. It works fine if I paint within the canvas, but if I get near the border of the canvas it translates and scales the painting.


I think when I get near the edge, the dimension of the painting canvas changes, which skews the image. How do I work around this, I set ClipToBounds="True" for both canvases already. How do I keep the mask canvas proportional to the painting canvas?

**Edit** - Here is the code behind for the two canvases.
The mask canvas:

```
<ItemsControl Name="maskDataBinding" Background="Transparent" Panel.ZIndex="-1" ClipToBounds="True" Height="512" Width="512" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="Transparent"  
                        Height="512" 
                        Width="512" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        ClipToBounds="True">
                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding Name}"
                            Width="{Binding Width}"
                            Height="{Binding Height}"
                            Opacity="{Binding Opacity}">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding OffsetX}" Y="{Binding OffsetY}"/>
                            <RotateTransform CenterX="{Binding CenterX}" CenterY="{Binding CenterY}" Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The painting canvas:

```
<!--Outer collection-->
<ItemsControl Name="canvasDataBinding"
            Focusable="True"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Height="512"
            Width="512" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            ClipToBounds="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"
                    MouseEnter="Canvas_MouseEnter"
                    MouseLeave="Canvas_MouseLeave"
                    MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown"
                    MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    ClipToBounds="True">

            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <!--nested collection-->
            <ItemsControl Height="512" Width="512" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSource}" ClipToBounds="True">

                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Background="Transparent"  
                                Height="512" 
                                Width="512" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                ClipToBounds="True">
                            <Canvas.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=maskDataBinding}"/>
                            </Canvas.OpacityMask>
                        </Canvas>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Name}"
                        Width="{Binding Width}"
                        Height="{Binding Height}"
                        Opacity="{Binding Opacity}">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding OffsetX}" Y="{Binding OffsetY}"/>
                                    <RotateTransform CenterX="{Binding CenterX}" CenterY="{Binding CenterY}" Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

My paint canvas is really just a collection of canvases (each canvas to simulate a layer). And each canvas has a collection of images. You can see I bind the OpacityMask inside the canvas of the nested collection.

**Edit**:
So my assumption is right. It skews the image when I get near the border because the painting canvas grows in width (if you get near the left/right borders) and grows in height (if you get near the top/bottom borders), so the mask gets stretched. Any ideas on a solution/workaround?


Here is another gif. I removed the opacity mask, so now im just painting on the canvas. I also set ClipToBounds=False on my painting canvas. The opacity mask is applied on this unclipped painting canvas whether ClipToBounds is false or true.

[image]

Comment: Add some borders to help you see what is going on

Comment: @RobertLevy
To the paintcanvas? Or the images that I am drawing?

Comment: Borders for everything, different colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just needed to apply the OpacityMask to any parent of the canvas. The OpacityMask sees everything on the canvas, even things outside the boundries (ClipToBounds set to True or False is irrelevant). The parent of the Canvas (in my case the actual ItemsControl) gets rid of any information outside the bounds of the Canvas, which is why applying the mask to the parent works.

```
<!--nested collection-->
<ItemsControl Height="512" Width="512" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSource}" >

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate>

            <Canvas Name="paintingCanvas"
                    Background="Transparent"  
                    Height="512" 
                    Width="512" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    ClipToBounds="True">
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Name}"
        Width="{Binding Width}"
        Height="{Binding Height}"
        Opacity="{Binding Opacity}">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding OffsetX}" Y="{Binding OffsetY}"/>
                        <RotateTransform CenterX="{Binding CenterX}" CenterY="{Binding CenterY}" Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=maskDataBinding}"/>
    </ItemsControl.OpacityMask>
</ItemsControl>
```